# Scala Trait Inner Class

Tags: scala, inheritance, inner-classes, traits

I have a whole group of classes, each of which contains a very similar inner class.

Simplified Example:

```
case class Schema1[V1](name1:String) extends Schema{
    case class Row1(p1:V1) extends Row
}

case class Schema2[V1,V2](name1:String, name2:String) extends Schema{
    case class Row2(p1:V1,p2:V2) extends Row
}

case class Schema3[V1,V2,V3](name1:String, name2:String, name3:String) extends Schema{
    case class Row3(p1:V1,p2:V2,p3:V3) extends Row
}
```

Is there a way to define in the Schema trait that all Schemas contain rows?

Comment: Have you tried defining a `Row` member inside the `Schema` trait?

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that a specific row were a member of each Schema?

Comment: Not if `Row` is an abstract class / trait. Which is probably what you'll want to define. Either that or a type class with an upperbound of `Row`.

Comment: I just added this,

    trait Schema{
        trait Row
    }

and it does more or less what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov then please add this as an answer so the question can be closed.

Comment: @Nalta I don't think that really does what you're looking for. The `trait Row` inside `Schema` isn't the same `Row` as it is in your original code sample. Each instance of a `Schema` will have a different type `Row` defined inside it. These are called path-dependent types.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about that, but the trait actually does a good job unifying all of them.